# How can i call other layout id with binding in android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding, binding

today I'm starting my new project with view binding. But, I have a problem which I don't know how to call another layout id with data binding. I want to call id 'txt_chapter_number' in chapter_item.xml
Is there anyone who can help me?

ChapterActivity.kt

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DividerItemDecoration
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.tutorial.kotlinfirebasecomicreader.databinding.ActivityChapterBinding

class ChapterActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var binding: ActivityChapterBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_chapter)

    binding.toolbar.title=com.tutorial.kotlinfirebasecomicreader.Common.Common.selected_comic!!.Name
    binding.toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_chevron_left_24)
    binding.toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener {
        finish() //GO BACK
    }

    binding.recyclerChapter.setHasFixedSize(true)
    val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@ChapterActivity)
    binding.recyclerChapter.layoutManager = layoutManager
    binding.recyclerChapter.addItemDecoration(DividerItemDecoration(this, layoutManager.orientation))

    binding.txt_chapter_number
}
}
```

activity_chapter.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ChapterActivity">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:titleTextColor="@color/textColor"
    android:background="@color/columnColor"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:weightSum="4"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_comic"
        android:text="Chapter (10)"
        android:textColor="@color/textColor"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_chapter"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

chapter_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="16dp"
android:background="@color/white">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_chapter_number"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:text="Chapter 1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

an answer from you will be very valuable to me as well as others
Thanks for your contribution

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to reference a different XML file unless you inflate that view. You could inflate it like so

```kotlin
val inflator = LayoutInflator.from(context)
val chapterItem = inflator.inflate(R.layout.chapter_item, null, false)
val txtChapterNumber = chapterItem.findViewById(R.id.txt_chapter_number)
```

However, you have not actually added this view into your layout yet, which you need to do in order to make it visible.

**A note about RecyclerViews**

Looking at your layout, it seems to me that you want your `reycler_chapter` Recycler View to then contain many `chapter_item`s. If this is the case, you need to create a [View Holder](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder) for your `chapter_item`, along with a [Recycler View Adapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter) which determines which `ViewHolder` to inflate. It might help read up on how RecyclerViews work.